# RDLC REPORT Print Button

Tags: rdlc

I am using RDLC Report for Client Side ,the print button is not visible in Google chrome ,i have tried this below link (I need to get the print preview screen with a button click) Thanking You Advance

[printing rdlc using report viewer 10.0.0.0, print button not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503352/printing-rdlc-using-report-viewer-10-0-0-0-print-button-not-showing)